# Excel Sheet Protection with specific Column filtering exception

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

When applying "sheet protection" rules on specific Excel sheets disabling filtering of tables. Is it possible to still allow filtering of specific columns in a protected sheet table?

to be more specific. I have a workbook used by various users. They can access the content only after inserting their credentials in a pop-up excel user form, which filteres my Master Table and Pivot to display only data relevant to the entered credentials. The user can still interact and update datea relevant to their credentials however he cannot filter the tables to see and manipulate data of other users.

However i would still like to allow the users to filter only one specific colum in the Master Data table.
Is this possible somehow via VBA?

Comment: Have you tried hiding columns?

Comment: Yes I did hide some columns and it works fine. but i would like to leave the filtering of one column in the table open, while the filtering of others are disabled but remain visible to the user as the columns contain user relevant data.

any ideas on how i could do that?